# Python. Remove duplicate elements from a list of list

Tags: python

I have a list with three levels with different num of elements, like this one:

```
>>> print some_list
[ [a], [[b,c],[b,c]], [[b,c],[b,c]], [d], [[e,f],[e,g]], [h,j,k,l,m] ]
```

How can I remove duplicate elements from it? 
Also, I want an output list with one level and all unique elements.
I've tried with `set()` function but it returns errors outputs.

Comment: what is your expected output? what errors? what is the exact code you tried?

Comment: What is the definition of duplicate? At the highest level?

Comment: Probably, a good starting point would be to look into why `list` can't be a member of a `set`: `list` is not hashable in Python.

Comment: Please update your question to clarify the level at which you want to remove elements, so people can upvote your question.

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers, I proved all and  worked very well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you just want a (single flat) list of all non duplicate elements. Although I'm sure this is a duplicate.

```
import itertools
print(list(set(itertools.chain(*itertools.chain.from_iterable(some_list)))))
```

Result:

```
>>> some_list = [ ['a'], [['b','c'],['b','c']], [['b','c'],['b','c']], ['d'], [['e','f'],['e','g']], ['h','j','k','l','m'] ]

>>> print(list(set(itertools.chain(*itertools.chain.from_iterable(some_list))))

['f', 'm', 'k', 'b', 'd', 'j', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'l']
```

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem to work at the level the OP seems to want, i.e. removing [[b,c],[b,c]] once.

Comment: you're right would have been an unhasable type error forgot there was further nesting. I updated to correct

Answer (score 0):

Used utility functions from HYRY in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434420/a-faster-nested-tuple-to-list-and-back).

Your set idea actually works, once you convert from list to tuple:

```
def list2tuple(a):
    return tuple((list2tuple(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in a))
def tuple2list(a):
    return list((tuple2list(x) if isinstance(x, tuple) else x for x in a))

l1=[ ['a'], [['b','c'],['b','c']], [['b','c'],['b','c']], ['d'], [['e','f'],['e','g']], ['h','j','k','l','m'] ]
#tuples are hashable, but lists aren't, so you have to convert to a tuple first
print  tuple2list(set(list2tuple(l1)))
```

output:

```
[['d'], ['a'], ['h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'], [['e', 'f'], ['e', 'g']], [['b', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First flatten your list, then use set():

```
your_list = [['a'], [['b', 'c'],['b', 'c']], [['b', 'c'], ['b', 'c']], ['d'], [['e', 'f'],['e', 'g']], ['h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']]

def flatten(items):
    for item in items:
       if isinstance(item, list):
           yield from flatten(item)  # Python 3.3
       else:
           yield item

print(sorted(set(flatten(your_list))))
```

output: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']